# How to Inject Spring values to Hibernate Type Definition class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is a Spring Hibernate implementation. I have defined a custom Type definition  where I need to pass

one default value to my custom Type Definition class as below.

But the value is null please help me what am I missing here ?

```
@TypeDef(name = "customString", typeClass = com.mydomain.EncryptString.class)
public class employee{

    private String empId;
    private String empName;
    @Type(type="customString")
    private String passportNumber;

      //setter and getters 
}


public class EncryptString mplements UserType{
    private String password; // inject via spring configurations

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        String encryptedPassport = rs.getString(names[0]);

        System.out.println(names.length);

        System.out.println("##"+password); // This null ????

        return ""
    }

    //password getters and setters methods

}
```

Spring configurations

```
<bean id="customString"
    class="com.mydomain.EncryptString">     
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

value of the password password in `nullSafeGet()` method it prints Null. How to make it

inject ? I expect Spring will load all the given default values and it instantiate values

when the EncryptString class call via Hibernate annotation.

**Updating my question with findings**

I have saw a example where TypeDef pass spring bean id as a parameter as below.

```
   @TypeDef(name = "encryptedString", typeClass =     
   org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType.class, parameters = { @Parameter(name 
   = "encryptorRegisteredName", value = "hibernateStringEncryptor") })
```

Spring configuration is

```
 <bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor"
    class="org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="registeredName" value="hibernateStringEncryptor" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="saltGenerator">         
        <bean class="org.jasypt.salt.FixedStringSaltGenerator">
            <property name="salt" value="salt"/>
        </bean>         
    </property>
```

hibernateStringEncryptor configuration is injected via type def passing the bean id as a

parameter. I went through the code http://www.jasypt.org/download.html but could not figure

out the way the bean get injected.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and you need the injection into EncryptString ? There may be a better way to get what you want done, but your example doesn't really express your intent very well

Comment: This is just a hypothetical business scenario. Please think only the technical requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `@Configurable` annotation because Spring doesn't instantiate the custom types, Hibernate does and Spring doesn't know about those instances. This is the [section in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-atconfigurable) that describes the scenario. I haven't used this approach myself, but `@Configurable` would be the first thing I'd try.

Basically, you need to annotate your `EncryptString` class with `@Configurable`, to add `spring-aspect.jar` to your project's classpath, to add `<context:spring-configured/>` to your xml config file and to enable AspectJ weaving. The documentation gives quite some details regarding this.

Comment: Thanks. Please refer the ticket after Updating my question with findings heading. Is there a way to pass bean id a Type def parameter and inject it. This is working. When de-compile the jasypt jar could not figureout the way this happen. But it is working.

Comment: What you added in there is different from what you asked initially. There is a new framework in there that you are using.

Comment: I looked over the code and I don't think they actually do injection: the `HibernatePBEStringEncryptor` has its field populated by injection, but what happens with `EncryptedStringType` is not Spring injection.

Comment: In [this code](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/jasypt/code/trunk/jasypt-hibernate3/src/main/java/org/jasypt/hibernate/encryptor/HibernatePBEStringEncryptor.java) when `setRegisteredName()` is called from Spring (inside the xml config file) a SINGLETON instance of `HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry` is created and the instance Spring created is "registered" with that singleton Registry.

Comment: If you look at [EncryptedStringType](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/jasypt/code/trunk/jasypt-hibernate3/src/main/java/org/jasypt/hibernate/type/AbstractEncryptedAsStringType.java) whenever `nullSafeGet` or `nullSafeSet` are called the same singleton `HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry` is checked and the encryptor registered (not injected) earlier - `HibernatePBEStringEncryptor` - is used, encryptor that has been created by Spring.

Comment: So, they use the Singleton pattern to get access to an instance of a bean created by Spring. This, I believe, is why that works but I may be wrong (I looked over the code for few minutes).

Comment: Yes got the point. The object setter methods access static instance and add all necessary fields. Accepting your previous answer too as it s also a solution for this issue

Comment: Hi Andrei, I am facing a similar issue where I have to instruct hibernate to use types without hibernate.cfg.xml. I have posted the question in SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890694/spring-use-hibernate-types-without-hibernate-cgf-xml  . Can you please check it out. Thanks a lot. :-)